# Set image size relative to page size

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am generating pdf files using FOP.
 is used to include images. My requirement is to set the width and height of image relative to the page size.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set only image width to `100%`

```
<img src="yourimage.jpg" width="100%"/>
```

Comment: Sorry there is some mistake in question.
I have to include the image using <fo:external-graphic>.